# Adding Client-Side jQuery Support

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

> How would you add client-side jQuery support to a program? I want to
>   start playing with jQuery in my web application, but before I do this,
>   I need to add code to include jQuery in my app.
>
> What code do I need to add to the app and where?

I have the following directories with the files:

routes/index.js

views/layout.jade

views/index.jade

views/notes.jade

views/edit.jade

views/updated.jade

bin/www

Answer (score 0):

You may include it with [Google Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/?csw=1%20Google%20Loader) in layout.jade:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
        google.load("jquery", "2.1");
        google.load("jqueryui", "1.11");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                //... your Code here
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js')
```

Comment: how would you write it in jade? I am not using HTML syntax. I am getting an error saying Unexpected Identifier

Comment: I've edited my answer, try it and tell me if it works.